# Could not cast value of type NSURL to NSString when String is specified (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, string, nsstring, nsurl

I have a method that is intended to load a website inside a `UIWebView`:

```
func setImageForURL(urlString:String, completion:((image:UIImage?)->Void)?) {

    self.completion = completion

    guard let url = NSURL(string: urlString) else {
        self.completion?(nil)
        return
    }

    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    webview = UIWebView(frame: self.bounds)
    webview!.delegate = self
    webview?.scalesPageToFit = true
    webview!.loadRequest(request);

}
```

That method is called in the following `loadWebsite` method:

```
func loadWebsite(item:ShareItem) {
    activitySpinner.startAnimating()
    imageView.setImageForURL((item.asset as? String)!) { (image) in
        self.showActionButton(true)
        self.activitySpinner.stopAnimating()
        self.actionButton.titleLabel?.text = "Open"
    }
}
```

I'm getting a crash at the following line:

`imageView.setImageForURL((item.asset as? String)!) { (image) in`

of `Could not cast value of type 'NSURL' (0x10fd8ee98) to 'NSString' (0x10eccdb48).`

I'm not understanding why, as I'm specifying the type to be a `String`, not an `NSString`. Anyone have some insight?

Comment: this is the error `item.asset as? String` check once it is NSURL or String, but it needs NSURL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't convert NSURL to String like that way (From your error log, I assume that `item.asset` returns an `NSURL` not a `String)`.

You need to use:

```
imageView.setImageForURL(item.asset.absoluteString) { (image) in
    self.showActionButton(true)
    self.activitySpinner.stopAnimating()
    self.actionButton.titleLabel?.text = "Open"
}
```

Comment: This appears to be working --- thank you! I'd like to understand why a bit more though. Looking at the docs, it looks like `absoluteString` is the exact conversion of the url to an `NSString`...am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: @narner: The issue is, in your code you are trying to type-cast NSURL to NSString. Actually what you want is you need to convert NSURL to NSString.

Comment: @narner: One example: Assume that you have some orange(NSURL) in your hand and you want to make juice(NSString/String) using that. What you are doing is, you are putting a label on the fruit saying "It's orange juice". What my code does is, it is converting the orange to orange juice, that is what you needed. (Not a good example, I think) :)

Comment: @narner: One more thing is the issue is not related with NSString or String. It is related with the function argument and function parameter mismatch (Some-times compiler error confuses).

Comment: Ah! Ok, I was wondering about that. That makes sense. I think I'm behind an Xcode update somewhere, so that could be part of it.

Answer (score 1):

Change the line

`imageView.setImageForURL((item.asset as? String)!) { (image) in`

to

`imageView.setImageForURL((item.asset as? NSURL)!) { (image) in`

if `item.asset` is a string  then thy this -

`imageView.setImageForURL(NSURL(string:(item.asset as? String)!)) { (image) in`

Comment: This will not execute because the function parameter is String, not URL